# Javascript API GET request CORS error

Tags: javascript, cors, trello

I'm very new so apologies if I use the wrong terminology. I am trying to pull data using Trello API but receive the following error in Chrome console:

> Failed to load https://api.trello.com/1/cards/5a42e19364345a7d84ba3f5f/members: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

After doing some research I have found this is a CORS problem. I am using Google App Engine with Python. Is this error something I can fix or is it a bug with the API? I have managed to do a POST request using this API no problem. I have read lots of information about CORS but haven't found a solution to the problem.

Here is my Javascript code for the GET request, it is just copy/pasted from the Trello API so I'm not sure what's wrong:

```
var authenticationSuccess = function() {
  console.log('Successful authentication');
};

var authenticationFailure = function() {
  console.log('Failed authentication');
};

window.Trello.authorize({
  type: 'popup',
  name: 'Work Requests App',
  scope: {
    read: 'true',
    write: 'true' },
  expiration: 'never',
  success: authenticationSuccess,
  error: authenticationFailure
});

var data = JSON.stringify(false);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
  if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
});

xhr.open("GET", "https://api.trello.com/1/cards/5a42e1936434a7d84ba3f5f/members");

xhr.send(data);
```

Comment: Why are you using `withCredentials = true`? Do you know [what it does](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials)?

Comment: Yes. If I set it to false it doesn't authenticate. Also why on earth did you mark this question as a duplicate? I am not using Java/Spring/Angular/SockJS, how are any of those answers supposed to help me? None of the answers apply and the issue only occurred for the OP in Chrome.

Comment: Re-opened. Didn't realise it was so different

Comment: Why aren't you using the [`client.js` API to perform the requests](https://developers.trello.com/v1.0/docs/clientjs#section-using-the-api)? Presumably it stores the required credentials after authorization and adds them to the request as parameters / headers. Also, I'd say you would need to perform these actions **after** authorization is successful (ie in the `authenticationSuccess` callback)

Comment: I assumed I was using `client.js` as it is included in my HTML `<script src="https://api.trello.com/1/client.js?key={key}"></script>` everything else in my javascript is copied from their documentation with the appropriate keys added.

Comment: What do you mean? You are clearly creating a new `XMLHttpRequest` object in your code and attempting to use that. You should be using `Trello.members.get('5a42e1936434a7d84ba3f5f', members => { ... })` or something similar.

Comment: I've raised an API docs bug for you ~ https://github.com/trello/api-docs/issues/150

Comment: In the meantime, I do suggest you try and use the `Trello` object methods.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look and submitting the request, I am taking a look at those methods now.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to combine together two different ways of working with Trello's API - using [client.js](https://developers.trello.com/docs/clientjs) and making direct HTTP requests.

I'd recommend starting off with using only `client.js` as it provides a number of helper functions when working with Trello's API. For instance, the `.authorize()` method will walk you through generating a token for your API key and will store it locally. To make the request to get a card's data you have in your example using only `client.js` your code should look something like this:

```
<html>
  <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://trello.com/1/client.js?key=XXXXXXXXX"></script>
  <script>

    var requestSuccess = function(response) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
    }

    var authenticationSuccess = function() {
      console.log('Successful authentication');
      // Now that you are authenticated, you can start
      // making requests to the API
      window.Trello.rest("GET", "cards/5a42e1936434a7d84ba3f5f/members", requestSuccess);
    };

    var authenticationFailure = function() {
      console.log('Failed authentication');
    };

    window.Trello.authorize({
      type: 'popup',
      name: 'Work Requests App',
      scope: {
        read: 'true',
        write: 'true' },
      expiration: 'never',
      success: authenticationSuccess,
      error: authenticationFailure
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

You'll need to include your API (obtained from visiting [trello.com/app-key](https://trello.com/app-key/) while logged into Trello) when you include `client.js` in the script. Replace the `XXXXXXXXX` above with your API key.

If you'd rather make direct HTTP requests to Trello's API, you will need to generate a Token (you can do so from the same page you retrieved your API key) and your code will look something like this:

```
<html>
  <script>  
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
      if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
        console.log(this.responseText);
      }
    });

    var yourToken = "XXXXXXXXXX";
    var yourKey = "XXXXXXXXXX";

    xhr.open("GET", "https://api.trello.com/1/cards/5a42e1936434a7d84ba3f5f/members?key=" + yourKey + "&token=" + yourToken);

    xhr.send();
  </script>
</html>
```

Again, you'll need to add in your API key and token.